# Solving first order ode by DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve an ODE in *Mathematica*, but there is no response.

This is the code I used:

```
eqn = x'[y] - c + a x[y] Sin[y - y0]  == 0;
sol = DSolve[eqn, x, y]
```

Could anyone help me? Is there another function that solves the problem?

Comment: Hi @Sara, you should look up the documentation for the DSolve and NDSolve. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html look the basic examples and copy/adapt them ;)

Answer (score 4):

`DSolve` is hanging on a definite integral with symbolic parameters. We can temporarily inactivate and reactivate `Integrate`, which in this case causes `DSolve` to return an indefinite integral that doesn't hang.

```
eqn = x'[y] - c + a x[y] Sin[y - y0]  == 0;

Block[{Integrate = Inactive[Integrate]},
  DSolve[eqn, x[y], y]
] // Activate
```

[image]

Comment: What is C[1] in te final answer?

Comment: @saranj it's an arbitrary constant. It's there because you had no initial condition.